Flutter Firebase Phone Auth not sending SMS Code
My Flutter Firebase Phone Auth not working anymore. I don't know but there may be some updates to the Firebase backend which I'm not aware of. I used to receive a verification code on a real device but now I don't anymore.
In my code, on a registration screen, I put in a phone number and press a button. Then when phone number verification is complete, it should send me to the OTP page.
I'm being sent to the OTP page alright, but I don't receive SMS code on my phone.
Phone verification method
sendPhoneNumber(
    BuildContext context,
    String phoneNumber,
    navigateToOTPScreen,
  ) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (error) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "An error occured ...${error.message}",
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.black);
          print(error.message);
          throw Exception(error.message);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          appData.verificationId = verificationId;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => navigateToOTPScreen,
            ),
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
      );
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "${e.message}",
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.black);
    }
  }

I've tried this on both Android and IOS real devices. My Phonesign-in method on Firebase console is enabled and the SHA-1 and SHA-256 key for android have are in place.
My Play Integrity for android is also registered but I don't know what seem to be the problem.
Any help, please?

Are you using the latest version of the authentication libraries?

Yes. firebase_auth: ^5.2.0

Since September 1 2024, projects on the free Spark plan can no longer send SMS for phone based sign-in. Check the Auth section in the Firebase pricing page for this.

To continue using phone based sign-in, you'll have to upgrade to the paid plan. Be sure to only enable SMS sending in regions where you expect active users and little/no abuse.

I'm not using the free Spark plan. I'm using the Blaze plan

There's a new SMS region policy in the Authentication > Settings section of Firebase. Now you have to enable and select regions where SMS is allowed. I was experiencing the same thing as you, and just now came across this.
